# How to convert Bitcoin cash address to cashAddress Format in PHP?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, address-generation

I've been trying with [cashaddress-php](https://github.com/btccom/cashaddress-php/tree/master/examples) but it doesn't work because the address should be in hex format, I tried with hex public hash key it also didn't work.

> ```
> Invalid hash length [320 bits] for pubkeyhash
> ```

Is there's any way to convert legacy bitcoin-cash address to copay(cashAddr)?

[Live example](https://bitpay.github.io/address-translator/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by decoding address from base58 then spliting it in version bit and payload and then assemble it into cashAddress and calculate checksum or if you want there is another project on github that claims to do that [Har01d/CashAddressPHP](https://github.com/Har01d/CashAddressPHP) maybe you should git it a try